# Dart and Flutter - How to obtain alpha months for locale - January, February, etc

Tags: dart, flutter

How can I obtain the list of alpha months in Dart/Flutter based on locale or a given locale?

EG. locale "en" List of months - January, February, etc.

I don't want to format a given date to obtain the information. I just want the alpha months as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_file.dart';
initializeDateFormatting("en_US", null).then((_) => {
        mDate = new DateFormat.MMM().format(new DateTime.now());
});
```

For more information visit follow URL,

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html

Comment: How does that give me a list of months? EG. locale "en" List of months - January, February, etc.